# Sinatra Logger for Web Service Errors

Tags: ruby, logging, error-handling, sinatra

I am using `Sinatra 1.3` and it's a `Sinatra::Application`.
I have a method that fetches a web service.
I want to log when this service has succeed and what it has failed as it runs in the background (cron job)

```
def fetch_some_web_service  
  begin  
    #if successful  
    log.info "Success"  
  rescue SocketError => e  
    log.info "Failed"
  end   
end
```

I can't seem to use the `Sinatra` `logger instance`.  It's generating errors for me and I'm assuming it's doing this because I'm logging in a method and not within a route?

What is the best way to capture the `errors` and `success` in some log file using `Sinatra::Application`

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in Sinatra for logging

```
raise "Log File not specified" if log_file_location == nil
log_file = File.new(log_file_location, "a")

$stdout.reopen(log_file)
$stderr.reopen(log_file)

$stdout.sync=true
$stderr.sync=true
```

Then use logger to log.

```
logger.info("it works !!!!")
```

Comment: Is the first 6 lines of code something I would put in my `helpers` or `before do` ?

Comment: No this code will go as part of the file, outside of any methods. In case you are using modular style of Sinatra then make it part of the class.